# How to delete cookie after Swagger authorization is removed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I configured my swagger to use HTTP Simple authentication to authenticate each endpoint call.

The configuration I used is like this:

```
private Docket docket () {
    return new Docket(SWAGGER_2)
       ....
       .build()
       .securitySchemes(securitySchemes())
       .securityContexts(securityContexts())
       ....
}

private List<SecurityScheme> securitySchemes() {
    return ImmutableList.of(new BasicAuth("Authorization"));
}

private List<SecurityContext> securityContexts() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .operationSelector(operationContext -> true)
            .build();
    return ImmutableList.of(securityContext);
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("basicAuth", "HTTP Basic Authentication");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
    SecurityReference securityReference = new SecurityReference("Authorization", authorizationScopes);
    return ImmutableList.of(securityReference);
}
```

The Swagger UI allows me to put username and password to authenticate each API call.

However, after I login, make a successful request and logout, the Swagger can still makes calls using my credential. This is because a Cookie still exist in the browser which can be used to authenticate against the endpoint.

How can I configure Swagger to remove the cookie upon logout?